# gstreamer Streaming 2 video into a single pipeline but only allow 1 video to stream through

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

we have 2 different videos streaming into a single pipeline, but would only like 1 video to arrive at the destination. Will GstPad be useful in this scenario?

I have tried using the following command but unable to drop 1 of the video, is gstreamer able to do this?

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc address=1.1.1.11 port=10002 ! queue ! tsdemux parse-private-sections=TRUE ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! 'video/x-h264' ! queue ! mpegtsmux alignment=7 ! udpsink host=2.2.2.2 port=10001 sync=false async=false
```

Below is the output as it shows it only receive 1 new pad.

```
Pipeline state changed from NULL to READY:
Pipeline state changed from READY to PAUSED:
Pipeline state changed from PAUSED to PLAYING:
Received new pad 'video_0_0100' from 'demux':
Received new pad video_0_0100, and it match 1 path1 name
Link succeeded (type 'video/x-h264').
```